# How to implement a single product and bundles consisting of a single product multiple times

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, bundle

I'm not totally new to magento but now I got a customer with a request I don't know how to implement.
For understanding I'd like to make an example first:

There is a product P for 10$.
For a customer it is possible to buy let's say 50 P for 500$.
But there should be the possibility to buy bundles (3,5,10,25,50 qty).
As example the bundle B exists of 25 times the product P and is sold for 220$ (30$ reduction).
So the customer can choose between buying 50 times product P or rather cheaper bundles.

Is there any uncomplicated way to implement this, giving the customer the option to choose instead of automatically go for pricing rules?

I appreciate any thoughts on that.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is best handled with [Tier prices](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing) which can be easily applied per product and even for specific customer groups. This would also eliminate the need to create extra bundled products.

If you want the user to buy per X products check out [this extension](http://www.appmerce.com/magento-commerce/multiples-of-x-batch-qty.html#.UiHepRv0G-I) from Appmerce. This combined with the tier prices would probably be a nice and not too expensive solution.
Overall they offer nice extensions and good support. I've used the extension on a shop selling wines where you can order either 1 bottle, a small case (3 bottles), a large case (6 bottles), 9, 12 or 15 bottles.

Comment: Tier pricing is unfortunatly not a possible solution.

It should be possible to buy 27 of product P, where 25 are in a bundle and 2 are out of a bundle
(in above example cost would be 220$ + 2*10$ instead of a price per product)

But thanks for pointing out tier pricing, I guess that would apply in other cases.

Comment: ah okay I understand now. I've looked for something like that before but couldn't find it. Would involve a lot of custome code, basically making your own price calculation model and perhaps hooking it to an observer for adding products to the cart